# Ubunto crontab reboot

Tags: cron

My crontab won't execute on reboot

**Step 1** : test.py

```py
Import os
os.mkdir("Testing")

sudo chmod +x testing.py
```

**Step 2** :

```
crontab -e
@reboot python /home/darkwar/Desktop/testing.py
```

Comment: And i rebooted it and it did not work at all

Answer (score 0):

You might want to point out that the bug in Ubuntu is easily solved by adding a delay: `@reboot sleep 60; <your command>.` To quote the thread, "my guess is that cron's @reboot directive is running too early in the boot process"

i.e:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && python /home/darkwar/Desktop/testing.py >> /home/me/reboot.log
```

in root cron; last parts only for debugging